# Is vacuum line still necessary with manual locking hubs on an F350?

Tags: ford, 4wd, f-350, vacuum

Several years ago, on my gas engine 2003 F350, I replaced my auto locking hubs with Warn manual hubs.

Recently I am experiencing the dreaded A/C defaulting to the defrost vents under low vacuum conditions due to a vacuum leak. I have isolated the leak/low vacuum issue to the auto locking hub system "vacuum solenoid". Is this piece still necessary with manual hubs? I was under the impression that the hub vacuum system was specifically for the auto hub system.

Comment: Did you try plugging the business end of the solenoid?

Comment: @Paulster2, not sure what you are asking.  I checked vacuum before and after the valve and at the main line to the heater control behind the glove box. With the valve disconnected and the line plugged I have good vacuum. With the valve in place normally I have poor vacuum at most all points. Problem is I don't have any real way to check the 4WD system right now with the valve disconnected. I'd need to find some nice mud somewhere. ;)

Comment: If the valve is what actuates the hubs, yet you replaced the hubs with Warn manual hubs, why would you still need the valve? Plug the holes and don't worry about it until you can get to somewhere you can test it, but ultimately I doubt you'll need the valve again. I thought it was throwing a code due to not having the valve in place, or something similar was going on. Just my opinion as I've not dealt with F350's before.

Comment: @Paulster2  Can you populate this with the answer in your comments?

Comment: Sorry for not following up on this. .... I did unplug the valve and cap off the line and all is well with the A/C. I am under the same assumption that the valve is no longer needed. No snow here in NYS yet so we'll have to wait and see if my assumptions are correct. ... Was just looking to see if anyone had this same issue to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try plugging the business end of the solenoid?

> I checked vacuum before and after the valve and at the main line to the heater control behind the glove box. With the valve disconnected and the line plugged I have good vacuum. With the valve in place normally I have poor vacuum at most all points. Problem is I don't have any real way to check the 4WD system right now with the valve disconnected. I'd need to find some nice mud somewhere.

If the valve is what actuates the hubs, yet you replaced the hubs with Warn manual hubs, why would you still need the valve? Plug the holes and don't worry about it until you can get to somewhere you can test it, but ultimately I doubt you'll need the valve again.